# center content of row display block Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap v4.3.1 but I did change on the **bootstrap.min.css file**
all the `display:flex;` replace by `display:block;`

because flex not working fine on printing mode on firefox .. anyway after changing this line any row class cannot be center even if I used justifice-content-center.

I think the reason because row class is block not flex so how do I center the content of row when its block?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

update #1 
Just to make it clear I am using edited Bootstrap as following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="'css/Editedbootstrap.css" />
```

so it's only on printing mode,[see the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414152/css-flex-box-not-printing-all-pages-on-firefox) to get more information on what type of problem I am facing

Comment: first of all, this is the wrong thing, you can not change `bootstrap.min.css` directly.

Comment: bootstrap internally manage all things using `flexbox`, so your `sm, md, lg, xl` will not working

Answer (score 0):

I warn you before posting an answer, `bootstrap.min.css` must not be changed directly.

> If you don't want to use `flexbox`, use `Bootstrap 3`

For centering any block like `.row`, you can use `text-center` class or use `CSS`.

```css
.row {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To position a div(block element) in the center, the technique is to make both the left and right margins auto and then give the div a width:

```
.center-div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```